# Where can I find the official school holiday schedule for Japan?

Tags: japan, school-holidays

I've been looking for some 20 minutes now and can't find any pertinent information. Where can I find the official school holiday calendar for Japan, 2013?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Japanese schools differ by area. In Hokkaido, the long winter means longer winter holidays. Opposite applies in the south. Public holidays are universal though, inc Golden Week. From my experience holidays are usually end Mar / start April, August and mid / end Dec to early January. New school year starts in April.

Comment: That's exactly my experience, too.  I teach at a Junior High School in Kanto.  In addition, individual schools can sometimes vary their own term times.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough I too have been looking for ages today for this information. Have just rung the Japanese embassy here in Sydney and am hoping they will come up with it.  I work at a Japanese school in Australia and we are trying to link our term dates with theirs and we still cannot find the schedule.

It will be roughly:

- Term 1: 10 April – July 20;
- Term 2: 1 September – 20 December;
- Term 3: 10 January – 20 March.

However, these dates were for 2008, not for 2012/13.

Comment: Wonderful. Please update your answer if you receive information from the embassy. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www.ithinkimlost.com/japan-jet-school-related/18113-academic-holiday-schedule-2012-2013-a.html), schools seem to differ depending on where they are.

The basics are [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_holiday#Japan).

If it's for travel, this should give you some idea at least.

Answer (score 1):

http://myschoolholidays.com/The-Japanese-School-15161

The golden week starting 29 of April and ending 5th of May, and some National holidays are not on the calender.